# How to make sure a pg_dump data file was properly restored?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am a novice when it comes to `postgres`, so please if anything below reads confusing feel free to assume error on my part.

I "inherited" an academic project that used postgres to build a data viz and demonstration dashboard.

The project was dormant for a while and had a rather old version of postgres running and what I actually got from my predecessor is "pg_dump.sql" files.

I was able to follow setup helps given on the [fedora help page](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/postgresql/).

Then use `sudo -u postgres -i`

Then `createdb <database_name>`

Then  `psql -U <username> -d <data_base_name>`

Then I used `psql -U username -d dbname < filename.sql` to restore one `pg_dump` file. (I have used the role/user that the `pg_dump.sql` had)

When I do `\dt`, I get the following output:

```
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | test | table | piims
(1 row)
```

but when I do `SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 500;` I get the following message:

```
 id
----
(0 rows)
```

The `pg_dump.sql` file is huge with north of 3.8 million lines of text. At about line 2700 the `pg_dump.sql` file has a line with this syntax `Data for Name: atgcat; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: ionuser; Owner: piims` and right below that syntax it has bioinformatics tabular data that looks familiar to my eye. Data that is missing from the "restored" database.

I tried the following syntax

```sql
SELECT 
    schemaname AS schema_name,
    relname AS table_name,
    n_live_tup AS row_count
FROM 
    pg_stat_user_tables
ORDER BY 
    n_live_tup DESC;
```

which then produced the following output:

```
schema_name |  table_name   | row_count
-------------+---------------+-----------
 ionuser     | obselem       |    532192
 ionuser     | normal        |    434981
 ionuser     | zscore        |    434981
 ionuser     | lineatg       |    395648
 ionuser     | pdiff         |    365206
 ionuser     | linecat       |    355161
 ionuser     | ppn           |    355158
 ionuser     | linecat_temp  |    353843
 ionuser     | parent        |    103452
 ionuser     | bgstat        |     77850
 ionuser     | pdstat        |     77850
 ionuser     | tube_elemnts  |     74454
 ionuser     | zstat         |     65601
 ionuser     | nstat         |     65601
 ionuser     | pot_elemnts   |     41688
 ionuser     | potbgexclude  |     39924
 ionuser     | atgcat        |     30676
 ionuser     | tube          |     29129
 ionuser     | potinfo       |     12294
 ionuser     | tubedets      |      7771
 ionuser     | compweight    |      5102
 ionuser     | traydets      |      4749
 ionuser     | potbg         |      2709
 ionuser     | orders        |       819
 ionuser     | ecotype       |       796
 ionuser     | trayinfo      |       309
 ionuser     | images        |       295
 ionuser     | wnanalysis    |       229
 ionuser     | typedets      |       201
 ionuser     | people        |       126
 ionuser     | ostat         |       110
 ionuser     | tubedef       |       108
 ionuser     | traydef       |        98
 ionuser     | atomic        |        30
 ionuser     | stdmtrl       |        13
 ionuser     | type          |        12
 ionuser     | status        |        10
 ionuser     | tlist         |         9
 ionuser     | icpmseq       |         5
 ionuser     | ppltype       |         5
 ionuser     | flag          |         3
 ionuser     | trayset       |         2
 ionuser     | calibmet      |         2
 ionuser     | elemlist      |         1
 ionuser     | rack          |         1
 ionuser     | rackshelf     |         0
 ionuser     | shelfposition |         0
 ionuser     | percentdiff   |         0
 public      | test          |         0
 ionuser     | shelf         |         0
(50 rows)
```

I the counts in the `row_counts` columns adds up to `3869204` which is quite close to the `wc -l` of the `pg_dump.sql` file (the file has 5,204 more lines). So, it looks like the tabular data from the file is in the `database` but not accessible or should not be accessible?

I am not sure what `schema` means in this context. Are the tables shown in the last table not meant to be accessible to me as a user? If no, could you point me in the right direction to understand the jargon at hand. If the data should be accessible, what should I do to make it so?

The data at hand is a product of few years worth of academic research and I want to recover it if possible.

Comment: The tables can be separated into different “schemas” which are like namespaces. You can have the same table name in different schemas. All your tables are in schema “ionizer” and not the default “public” so they don’t show up with \dt unless you ask for them. Use “\dt ionuser.” (Note the dot)

Comment: Check your restore proces, you got errors or you didn't get any.

Comment: A database consists of more than a single table. Just because the `test` table is empty doesn't mean that the other tables are empty. You know that the restore went well if `pg_dump` doesn't report any errors and returns with return code 0.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe When I `<` the `pg_dump` file, on the terminal, a series of what must be `postgres` commands are executed. The only error is `ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql` and most everything else is along the lines of

`CREATE FUNCTION`
`ALTER FUNCTION`
`COMMENT`
`CREATE FUNCTION`
`ALTER FUNCTION`
`COMMENT`
`CREATE FUNCTION`
`ALTER FUNCTION`
`COMMENT`

Comment: That looks as it should. To avoid the error, restore the dump with a superuser (`-U postgres`). But if that's the only error, everything seems to have worked fine.